# Acumatica Report Writer extract date from date time field

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica advanced report writer i have a date parameter but when i print this it shows in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS format.  What is the format syntax so it only shows the date in DD/MM/YYYY format?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the report designer format field:
[image]

Date format syntax is from .Net Framework:
[custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

If you need a hardcoded format (with slashes) use 'dd/MM/yyyy'.

If you only want the short date format (date without time) use 'd'.
I would pick 'd' format if all you want is to remove time because it will follow the culture and still provide a short date.

Example: 'MM-dd-yyyy' or 'dd/MM/yyyy' etc...